# Sens du mot donnée

Tags: sens

[image]

Quel est le sens du mot **donnée** dans cette phrase ?
Et quel est le sens du mot **revue** dans cette phrase ?

Answer (score 3):

Données :  les informations.
Revue : analyse.

Answer (score 3):

***Revue*** (du verbe revoir) a ici le sens [B.- 1. du TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revue/1):

> Action, fait d'examiner de nouveau; fait de reprendre point par point les divers éléments, les divers aspects d'une question.

***Données*** a son sens habituel, celui du latin *data*, ici tous les faits, toutes les informations que l'on est amené à connaitre.

Answer (score 2):

Le sens de « donnée » qui convient est le suivant.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donn%C3%A9e)) **B.** − P. ext.
> **1.** Ce qui est connu et admis, et qui sert de base, à un raisonnement, à un examen ou à une recherche.
> ♦ Toute question de politique intérieure doit être vidée d'après les données de la statistique départementale.  (Proudhon, Propriété,1840, p. 340)
> ♦ Les données actuelles de l'embryologie  (Bergson, Évol. créatr.,1907, p. 25)
> ♦ ... cette seule constatation doit nous inciter à chercher, pour les phénomènes de régénération, une interprétation moins philosophique et plus conforme aux données de l'expérience. J. Rostand, La Vie et ses probl.,1939, p. 72.

Le mot « information » peut être utilisé en tant que synonyme.

« Revue » a le sens suivant.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/revue)) **C.** − [La notion d'action que l'on renouvelle s'efface, parfois jusqu'à disparaître]
> **1.** Action, fait d'examiner avec attention chacun des éléments d'un ensemble. Synon. inspection.
> ♦ Enfin, le grand jour arriva. Monsieur se leva de bonne heure, inquiet, nerveux, agité (...). Cinq ou six fois (...) [Madame] passa la dernière revue de l'hôtel, dérangea et remit sans raison des bibelots et des meubles, alla d'une pièce dans l'autre, sans savoir pourquoi.  (Mirbeau, Journal femme ch., 1900, p. 197)

La paraphrase « L'inspection sélective correspond … » pourrait donc être utilisée.